# Arduino code for XBee

Tags: xbee

I am trying to send analog data, from a LM35, using an XBee (series 1 - XB24).

My setup:

- Transmitting Module: XBee with USB explorer+Arduino+LM35 (temperature sensor)
- Receiving Module: XBee with XBee shield+Arduino

I read analog data using the Arduino and send it through the XBee in the USB explorer, then the receiving XBee module receives it and shows it in the serial monitor of the Arduino.

I have tried many ways but I can't reach it and I have figured out that my problem lies in the Arduino code.

So, please can anyone help with some demo code for this project?

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far, and what part you think is broken?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at Robert Faludi's book [*Building Wireless Sensor Networks*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807740.do), published by O'Reilly. He describes, step by step, a very similar project, but without the Arduino.

Or Alasdair Allan's [*Distributed Network Data*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028802.do), also published by O'Reilly, which has a similar project using an Arduino.

Also, take a look at Robert Faludi's blog [TMP36 Instructions: Simple Sensor Network](https://www.faludi.com/bwsn/tmp36-instructions-simple-sensor-network/).